# RedirecToAction doesnt call the expected view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have successfully created a product but the page doesn't redirects to the view I want...and I don't really know why...
[HttpPost]
public async Task AddProduct([FromForm] AddProductViewModel model)

The jquery call:

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: '/' + 'Product' + '/' + 'AddProduct',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: console.log('success'),

    });
//edit

   $.ajax({
        url: '/Product/AddProduct',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: window.location.href = "/Product/ProductList"

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST. When you redirect somewhere, the HTTP "Location" header tells the browser where to go, and the browser makes a GET request for that page. You'll probably have to just write the code for your page to accept GET requests as well as POST requests.

You can return the name of the view you want instead of the redirect, write as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddProduct()
{
  bool isFoo = handleBar();

  if (isFoo)
  {
    return View();
  }

   return View("ProductList");
 }
```

if you are using ajax  you can redirect user in client side such as the following code:

```
$.ajax({            
   //settings
 }).done(function (r) {
    window.location.href = '/Product/ProductList';
 });
```

or use success

```
$.ajax({
//settings
success: function(res) {
    window.location.href = '/Product/ProductList';
   }
});
```

Comment: so... on(in ajax) success I would make an http get request with ajax?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: as you told me to call directly onto the action it wasnt working but calling the view as if it was the view I need it was working as expected

Answer (score 1):

When you use ajax you can not redirect on the server side. So you have two choices

1. Add form and  submit button to your view, and use it to submit data. In this case you will be redirected from action on the server side.
2. Or fix your  succes ajax part

```
success: window.location.href='@Url.Action("ProductList","Product")';

//or 

success:  window.location.href = "/product/productList" ;
```

Comment: well I have added a GET  request on success and it doesnt redirects at all to the Action i am making the request to

Comment: @PontiacGTX I am sorry can you show your code pls? I can't see any get request in my answer.  You just repeating your self again by putting a new get . Make it precisely as in my answer

Comment: please,check again the original post i haved updated it,Thansk

Comment: @PontiacGTX I just checked it. Ajax will never redirect you as I told already.  User window.location.href as it is my answer.

Comment: it doesnt redirect with the new href location in the success part, (see latest acitivty https://imgur.com/a/TSiaBFe) it stays in the same view I have also tried with window.location.replace( "/Product/ProductList")

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LOUKzeS the specific request that is marked as cancelled